# Evaluate: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor kx\rfloor}{n^2}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Evaluate: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor kx\rfloor}{n^2}$$

---

**My approach**:

I  simply use this.
$$
\boxed{x-1 < \lfloor x\rfloor \leq x}
$$
to apply *squeeze theorem*
and finally come to this conclusion,
$$\frac{\left\lfloor x\left(\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)-n\right)\right\rfloor}{n^2}< \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
\text { Required number } \\
\end{array}\right)}{n^2} \leq \frac{x\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)}{n^2}$$

taking limit($n\to\infty$) to LHS & RHS I am getting $\frac{x}2$

**I am looking for any other method better than this.Any suggestion or hint would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Other than squeeze , i dont see any other method. U cud convert to fraction and apply sandwich, but its the same method

Comment: yeah! that's why i am looking for.

Comment: For greatest integer, you could use $\lceil x \rceil$ (```\lceil``` and ```\rceil```).

Comment: @K.defaoite: the informal "greatest integer" denotes the "greatest integer not larger than the argument" and is the $\text{floor}$ function.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lfloor kx\rfloor=kx-\{kx\},$$ where $0\le\{kx\}<1$.

The summation gives

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}x-\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\{kx\}=\frac x2+\frac1n\left(\frac12-\overline{\{kx\}}\right)\to\frac x2$$

because $0\le\overline{\{kx\}}<1$.

Comment: For the summation the index should be $k$